# Show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n e^{i n \theta} = \frac{1- r\cos(\theta)+i r \sin(\theta)}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Show that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n e^{i n \theta} = \frac{1- r\cos(\theta)+i r \sin(\theta)}{1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta)},$$ where $0\leq r <1$.

Using this, prove that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n \cos(n\theta)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n \sin(n\theta)$ are convergent.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Why was this upvoted? The questioner showed no effort.

Comment: +1 Good question. Well formulated. Very useful for many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n$ is convergent provided $|z|<1$, and we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n=\frac{1}{1-z} \quad |z|<1.
$$
So if we set $z=re^{i\theta}$, we have $r=|z|$, and therefore for every $0 \le r <1$ we get
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^ne^{in\theta}=\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}}=\frac{1-re^{-i\theta}}{(1-re^{i\theta})(1-re^{-i\theta})}=\frac{1-r\cos\theta+ir\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}.
$$
I'm guessing that what want to deduce is that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\cos(n\theta)$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\sin(n\theta)$ are convergent provided $0 \le r <1$.

This follows from the fact 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^ne^{in\theta}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\cos(n\theta)+i\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\sin(n\theta)
$$ is convergent and so we have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\cos(n\theta)=\frac{1-r\cos\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2},\quad
\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\sin(n\theta)=\frac{r\sin\theta}{1-2r\cos\theta+r^2}.
$$

Answer (score 9):

The first sum is a geometric series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{r^ne^{in\theta}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(re^{i\theta})^n$$ 
$$=\frac{1}{1-re^{i\theta}} = \frac{1}{1-r\cos\theta -ir\sin{\theta}}\cdot\frac{1-r\cos\theta + ir\sin\theta}{1-r\cos\theta + ir\sin\theta} =\frac{1-r\cos\theta + ir\sin\theta}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}$$

For the next two sums notice that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{r^ne^{in\theta}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{r^n\cos(n\theta) + i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r^n\sin(n\theta)}$$

So $$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{r^n\cos(n\theta)}} = \frac{1-r\cos\theta}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}$$ $$\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{r^n\sin(n\theta)}} = \frac{r\sin{\theta}}{1+r^2-2r\cos\theta}$$