# How to find the value of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty r^n \sin(n\theta)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Question is to find the value of

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n \sin(n\theta)\text{ for }r=0.5\text{ and }\theta=\pi/3$$

I don't know any tools which can solve this question.

Comment: See [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/548162/147263)

Comment: Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex).